Cast non-primitive type in Rust
I am very new to Rust, so apologies if this is a simple question!
I have the following simplified scenario, where I have a trait and two struct types (TypeA and TypeB) that implement the trait. I then have a vector of traits that contains instances of both TypeA and TypeB.
Later on, I would like to iterate the vector and access fields that belong only to TypeA or TypeB depending on what the type is. Below is what I have written. My attempt is to match the type of each item and then downcast the boxed trait iterator to the struct. This works with a & reference, but how can I achieve a mutable reference &mut.
For the & reference consider the following ...
use std::any::Any;

trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct TypeA{field_a: u16}
impl MyTrait for TypeA {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("TypeA is doing something.");
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
   }
}

struct TypeB{field_b: u16}
impl MyTrait for TypeB {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("TypeB is doing something.");
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
   }
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = vec![
        Box::new(TypeA{field_a:10}),
        Box::new(TypeB{field_b:20}),
    ];

    for item in &vec {
        // Downcast the trait object to its concrete type

        if let Some(type_a) = item.as_any().downcast_ref::<TypeA>() {
            type_a.do_something();
            print!("{}", type_a.field_a);
        } else if let Some(type_b) = item.as_any().downcast_ref::<TypeB>() {
            type_b.do_something();
            print!("{}", type_b.field_b);
        } else {
            println!("Unknown type");
        }
    }
}

However, I want to modify the fields within the downcasted instance, such as
type_a.field_a = 100;


@freakish Since the trait supports casting to a dyn Any, this is indeed possible, though inefficient and probably ill-advised.

If you have only two types (or really, any fixed set of types), you are probably better off using an enum.

Thanks all for your comments - I modified the question a little to show that I can achieve the cast back to the instance type, but also to focus on obtaining a mutable reference to the instance. It appears that simply adding &mut doesn't quite work, and I am not familiar enough with Rust to fix it.
However, I don't doubt that there is a better - more "Rust" way to achieve this, so if there is a better way please let me know!

You're using a by-shared-reference iteration, you can't get a mutable reference out of that and thus can't modify the referee. You need to use iter_mut (or for item in &mut vec, and declare your vec with let mut vec), then use Any::downcast_mut to downcast to a concrete mutable reference.

You can do this if you add a way to get a &mut dyn Any on your trait:
fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any;

The implementation is the same as as_any:
fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Any {
    self
}

You will also need to make vec mutable, and iterate over &mut vec instead of &vec, and then you will be able to do this, for example:
item.as_any_mut().downcast_mut::<TypeA>()

This gives you an Option<&mut TypeA>.

However, I would strongly suggest you consider using an enum instead of boxed trait objects.  If you have a closed set of variants you need to support, this will be considerably more ergonomic.

Thanks very much this worked perfectly. I am curious why you recommend an enum instead of boxed traits. Is is a safety thing, or performance related or just a bad design? Thanks again

@RedPen Both safety, performance, and ergonomics. Safety - using exhaustive matches, enum allow you to make sure you don't forget to handle any case, and they also make sure you don't try downcasting to an incorrect type. Performance - enums come without need for boxing, which improves caching and creation time, and downcasting making use of dynamic dispatch makes it really inefficient compared to the match on enums. Ergonomics - downcasting isn't really ergonomic, and even when you don't need it enums make it easy to group together operations on different types (the expression problem)

@RedPen Really, their only disadvantage is when there is one large variant, in which case all other variants will also be large, but that too can be mitigated with boxing.

@RedPen Another option would be to use your types polymorphically -- that is, only through the trait members, with no downcasting. If you have to downcast that's an indication that you're thinking about things in a very wrong way. The trait itself should define everything you need to use the value. In this case that might mean providing get and set methods on the trait for the contained u16 value. fn value(&self) -> u16; fn set_value(&mut self, value: u16);

@RedPen Though I obviously don't speak for cdhowie, please be aware that the recommendation against trait objects only applies when you're downcasting to concrete types. In that case you're very likely better off with an enum. Of course, there are exceptions, and Any exists for good reason, but it should probably not be the first tool you reach for.

@RedPen if you want more details on the design considerations between using dynamic dispatch vs enums, I would recommend this answer. The question was about OCaml so the examples are given in that language, but I think the explanations are understandable even if you don't' know OCaml.
